# Is it possible to style anonymous flex items explicitly?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm in the early stages of grasping the basic flexbox concepts. The [Using CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) article at MDN states (emphasis mine):

> Each child of a flex container becomes a flex item. **Text directly contained in a flex container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.**

That means that the following mark-up automatically provides three items to play with:

```css
p, em {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}
em {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a <em>just</em> a test.</p>
```

However, I'm still unsure about the possibilities of these anonymous items outside flexbox model itself (if any). It's awesome not to need to wrap "This is a" and "a test" in bogus `<span>` tags for layout but, is there a way to apply regular styles to them? A pseudo-element or something similar? Could I, for instance, set a different colour to each one of the three parts the paragraph is divided into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Anonymous boxes cannot be directly targeted for CSS styling. CSS styles need a "hook" in the HTML to attach to. That hook is an HTML tag. Without the tag, CSS has nothing to target. This concept applies across box models, including *flex* and *block* formatting contexts.

---

More about anonymous boxes:

*From the CSS spec:*

> [**9.2.2.1 Anonymous inline
>   boxes**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous)
>
> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element
>   must be treated as an anonymous inline element.

The flexbox specification provides for similar behavior.

> [**4. Flex Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)
>
> Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each
>   contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex
>   container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

Comment: Now I think about it, it certainly makes sense.

Comment: ... and that's why they're called "anonymous" boxes.

Comment: So it's kinda a virtual container for the text nodes directly contained in a flex container? Correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Obviously not, since otherwise all text in the following example would have to be styled like the word "just":

```css
p,
em {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

em {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: inline-flex;
}

p * {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a <em>just</em> a test.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the experimental proof. While you were composing your answer I finally found a reference in the most obvious place (the W3C recommendation), I've added an answer with the link.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible.

The [W3C Candidate Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items) says:

> Note also that the **anonymous item’s box is unstyleable, since there is
>   no element to assign style rules to**. Its contents will however inherit
>   styles (such as font settings) from the flex container.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is still 'no', but a little but often-needed „addition“**

`display: flex` has a bigger effect on the *children* then on the styled element itself (which will be block, or whatever it's parent and the `flex:`-property (not value) dictates). Also the accompanying `align-items: center` [actually affects](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) the *children*.

[image]

**tl;dr; anonymous inner element are affected by *flex styling*, behaving like an element on their own** (just not by others styling attempts). [Codepen](https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/XGMzaP?editors=1100)

```
<i> + <div> hello </div><div> there </div></i>
```

Sass:

```
i
  background: #faa
  padding: 12
  padding: 0 20px
  height: 100px

  // affects innner text
  display: flex
  align-items: center

  * // affects only actual tags
    background: cyan
```