# Centering in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, centering, css-grid

I'm trying to create a simple page with CSS Grid.

What I'm failing to do is center the text from the HTML to the respective grid cells.

I've tried placing content in separate `div`s both inside and outside of the `left_bg` and `right_bg` selectors and playing with some of the CSS properties to no avail.

How do I do this?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  grid-gap: 0px 0px;
}

.left_bg {
  display: subgrid;
  background-color: #3498db;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  z-index: 0;
}

.right_bg {
  display: subgrid;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  grid_row: 1 / 1;
  z-index: 0;
}

.left_text {
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  justify-self: center;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: large;
}

.right_text {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  grid_row: 1 / 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  justify-self: center;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--everything on the page-->

  <div class="left_bg">
    <!--left background color of the page-->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="right_bg">
  <!--right background color of the page-->
</div>

<div class="left_text">
  <!--left side text content-->
  <p>Review my stuff</p>

  <div class="right_text">
    <!--right side text content-->
    <p>Hire me!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check the link https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html, I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 971, accepted):

This answer has two main sections:

1. Understanding how alignment works in CSS Grid.
2. Six methods for centering in CSS Grid.

If you're only interested in the solutions, skip the first section.

---

### The Structure and Scope of Grid layout

To fully understand how centering works in a grid container, it's important to first understand the structure and scope of grid layout.

The HTML **structure** of a grid container has three levels:

- the container
- the item
- the content

Each of these levels is independent from the others, in terms of applying grid properties.

The **scope** of a grid container is limited to a parent-child relationship.

This means that a grid container is always the parent and a grid item is always the child. Grid properties work only within this relationship.

Descendants of a grid container beyond the children are not part of grid layout and will not accept grid properties. (At least not until the [**`subgrid`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929369/3597276) feature has been implemented, which will allow descendants of grid items to respect the lines of the primary container.)

Here's an example of the structure and scope concepts described above.

Imagine a tic-tac-toe-like grid.

```css
article {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}
```

[image]

You want the X's and O's centered in each cell.

So you apply the centering at the container level:

```css
article {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

But because of the structure and scope of grid layout, `justify-items` on the container centers the grid items, not the content (at least not directly).

[image]

```css
article {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  justify-items: center;
}

section {
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <section>X</section>
    <section>O</section>
    <section>X</section>
    <section>O</section>
    <section>X</section>
    <section>O</section>
    <section>X</section>
    <section>O</section>
    <section>X</section>
</article>
```

Same problem with `align-items`: The content may be centered as a by-product, but you've lost the layout design.

```css
article {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

```css
article {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section {
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <section>X</section>
    <section>O</section>
    <section>X</section>
    <section>O</section>
    <section>X</section>
    <section>O</section>
    <section>X</section>
    <section>O</section>
    <section>X</section>
</article>
```

To center the content you need to take a different approach. Referring again to the structure and scope of grid layout, you need to treat the grid item as the parent and the content as the child.

```css
article {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

[image]

```css
article {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section>X</section>
  <section>O</section>
  <section>X</section>
  <section>O</section>
  <section>X</section>
  <section>O</section>
  <section>X</section>
  <section>O</section>
  <section>X</section>
</article>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vx58mrpp/8/)

---

### Six Methods for Centering in CSS Grid

There are multiple methods for centering grid items and their content.

Here's a basic 2x2 grid:

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}


/* can ignore styles below; decorative only */
grid-container {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
grid-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

### Flexbox

For a simple and easy way to center the content of grid items use flexbox.

More specifically, make the grid item into a flex container.

There is no conflict, spec violation or other problem with this method. It's clean and valid.

```css
grid-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

grid-item {
  display: flex;            /* new */
  align-items: center;      /* new */
  justify-content: center;  /* new */
}

/* can ignore styles below; decorative only */
grid-container {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
grid-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

See this post for a complete explanation:

- [How to Center Elements Vertically and Horizontally in Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)

---

### Grid Layout

In the same way that a flex item can also be a flex container, a grid item can also be a grid container. This solution is similar to the flexbox solution above, except centering is done with grid, not flex, properties.

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

grid-item {
  display: grid;            /* new */
  align-items: center;      /* new */
  justify-items: center;    /* new */
}

/* can ignore styles below; decorative only */
grid-container {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
grid-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

---

### `auto` margins

Use `margin: auto` to vertically and horizontally center grid items.

```css
grid-item {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

grid-item {
  margin: auto;
}

/* can ignore styles below; decorative only */
grid-container {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
grid-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

To center the content of grid items you need to make the item into a grid (or flex) container, wrap anonymous items in their own elements ([since they cannot be directly targeted by CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43027851/3597276)), and apply the margins to the new elements.

```css
grid-item {
  display: flex;
}

span, img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

grid-item {
  display: flex;
}

span, img {
  margin: auto;
}

/* can ignore styles below; decorative only */
grid-container {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
grid-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item><span>this text should be centered</span></grid-item>
  <grid-item><span>this text should be centered</span></grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

---

### Box Alignment Properties

When considering using the following properties to align grid items, read the section on `auto` margins above.

- `align-items`
- `justify-items`
- `align-self`
- `justify-self`

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#property-index

---

### `text-align: center`

To center content horizontally in a grid item, you can use the [**`text-align`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) property.

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  text-align: center;  /* new */
}


/* can ignore styles below; decorative only */
grid-container {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
grid-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

Note that for vertical centering, `vertical-align: middle` will not work.

This is because the [**`vertical-align`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property applies only to inline and table-cell containers.

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  text-align: center;     /* <--- works */
  vertical-align: middle; /* <--- fails */
}


/* can ignore styles below; decorative only */
grid-container {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
grid-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item>this text should be centered</grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

One might say that `display: inline-grid` establishes an inline-level container, and that would be true. So why doesn't `vertical-align` work in grid items?

The reason is that in a [**grid formatting context**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-item-display), items are treated as block-level elements.

> [**6.1. Grid Item
>   Display**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-item-display)
>
> The `display` value of a grid item is ***blockified***: if the
>   specified `display` of an in-flow child of an element generating a
>   grid container is an inline-level value, it computes to its
>   block-level equivalent.

In a [**block formatting context**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting), something the `vertical-align` property was originally designed for, the browser doesn't expect to find a block-level element in an inline-level container. That's invalid HTML.

---

### CSS Positioning

Lastly, there's a general CSS centering solution that also works in Grid: *absolute positioning*

This is a good method for centering objects that need to be removed from the document flow. For example, if you want to:

- [Center text over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35871294/3597276), or
- [Place asterisks (*) above required form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45599317/3597276)

Simply set `position: absolute` on the element to be centered, and `position: relative` on the ancestor that will serve as the containing block (it's usually the parent). Something like this:

```css
grid-item {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

grid-item {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

span, img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* can ignore styles below; decorative only */

grid-container {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}

grid-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item><span>this text should be centered</span></grid-item>
  <grid-item><span>this text should be centered</span></grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
  <grid-item><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

Here's a complete explanation for how this method works:

- [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

Here's the section on absolute positioning in the Grid spec:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#abspos

Comment: is `grid-container` & `grid-item` are HTML tags?

Comment: They are *custom* HTML tags. You can create your own tags, as I did for this demo. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36380449/3597276 @pro.mean

Comment: This is a wonderful answer, thank you. It made me realize, in your two first examples, that between `flex` and `grid`, `align-items` stays the same but for some reason `justify-content` becomes `justify-items`

Comment: This may provide a useful explanation: [The difference between `justify-self`, `justify-items` and `justify-content`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48535585/3597276) @WoJ

Comment: changing `display: block` to `display: flex` worked for me

Comment: Two of your code snippets, when run, do not produce correct results--one is not centered, another is missing background. Figured you'd want to know so you can clean up this otherwise _excellent_ answer.

Comment: this is a detailed one. my +1 on this

Comment: I am not gonna read all that, just use Konrad Albrecht's answer.

Answer (score 104):

Do not even try to use flex and stay with css grid. Just add the following on the content element:

```
place-self: center;
```

and it will do the centring work here.

If you want to center something that is inside `div` that is inside grid cell, you need to define nested grid in order to make it work.
Both examples shown in the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr5mjgaw/).

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I was wondering about the nested grids. Thanks for showing me how its done I guess. So you think flex should be avoided with grid or is it fine to combine?

Comment: Its fine to combine but you need to be sure that you are using right tool for the job.
Find some time and watch Rachels presentation, that will clarify alot for you in topic of css grid.

https://youtu.be/3vJE3bVoF-Q

Comment: The problem with this approach occurs when you're using borders on the grid items...

Comment: This can be shortened by `place-self: center;`.

Answer (score 83):

The CSS [place-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items) shorthand property sets the align-items and justify-items properties, respectively. If the second value is not set, the first value is also used for it.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

Comment: `place-items` is not currently supported in edge

Comment: Underrated answer. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The only answer I was looking for. Thx @CloudBranch.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=place-items Edge support should be fine now.

Answer (score 21):

You can use flexbox to center your text. By the way no need for extra containers because text is considered as anonymous flex item.

From [flexbox specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items):

> Each in-flow child of a [flex container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) becomes a [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item), and each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a [flex container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) is wrapped in an anonymous [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item). However, an anonymous flex item that contains only [white space](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) (i.e. characters that can be affected by the [`white-space`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space) property) is not rendered (just as if it were `display:none`).

So just make grid items as flex containers (`display: flex`), and add `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` to center both vertically and horizontally.

Also performed optimization of HTML and CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: large;
}

.left_bg,
.right_bg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left_bg {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.right_bg {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left_bg">Review my stuff</div>
  <div class="right_bg">Hire me!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

We can use `place-items: center;` property in parent element to make child elements text in center.

```css
.parent {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    place-items: center;
 }
 
 .parent > div {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">child2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would vertically center the table as well (each element in each row having different top point, depending on its height). Is there a way to only horizontally center the table?

Answer (score 5):

Make parent a grid and `justify-content: center;` and `align-content: center;`

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.child {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Try using flex:

Plunker demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/nk02ojKuXD2tAqZiWvf9

```
/* Styles go here */

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  grid-gap: 0px 0px;
}

.left_bg {
  background-color: #3498db;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

.right_bg {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  grid_row: 1 / 1;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
  <!--everything on the page-->

  <div class="left_bg">
    <!--left background color of the page-->
    <div class="text">
      <!--left side text content-->
      <p>Review my stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right_bg">
    <!--right background color of the page-->
    <div class="text">
      <!--right side text content-->
      <p>Hire me!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```css
.d-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.d-grid div {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-grid">
  <div>text 1</div>
  <div>text 2</div>
  <div>text 3</div>
  <div>text 4</div>
  <div>text 5</div>
  <div>text 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

You want this?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  grid-gap: 0px 0px;
}

.left_bg {
  display: subgrid;
  background-color: #3498db;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  z-index: 0;
}

.right_bg {
  display: subgrid;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  grid_row: 1 / 1;
  z-index: 0;
}

.text {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--everything on the page-->

  <div class="left_bg">
    <!--left background color of the page-->
    <div class="text">
      <!--left side text content-->
      <p>Review my stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right_bg">
    <!--right background color of the page-->
    <div class="text">
      <!--right side text content-->
      <p>Hire me!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite. The text should be vertically aligned too.

Comment: Use
`.text{
font-family: Raleway;
font-size: large;
text-align: center;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
}
`