# Vertical align inside CSS grid

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-grid

I would like to have a giant progressbar which is vertically aligned inside a CSS grid.

The problem is, vertical alignment inside CSS grid is not working for me.  I tried on Firefox, and also on Chrome.

I tried `vertical-align: middle`, but it is not working. I have put a Flexbox inside the grid item, but still it is not working.

Here is my minimal example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.two {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

.three {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: violet;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

.four {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: aqua;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

progress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 0;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="vertical">
      <progress max="100" value="80">
            <div class="progress-bar">
              <span style="width: 80%;">Progress: 80%</span>
            </div>
          </progress>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="three"> Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

A demo:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOpdPW

How do I align the progressbar vertically (inside its grid item) of the above demo project?

Comment: [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45536537/3597276)

Comment: you can eventually center box `.two` to use the mimal CSS  required `.two {align-self:center;}` . https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPJZMv  see this quiet clear tutorial for beginners: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the Flexbox solution, you have to add `display:flex` and `align-items: center` to **.two**, so the CSS becomes like this:

```
.two {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: yellow;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Then add `flex: 1` to **.vertical**:

```
.vertical {
    flex: 1
}
```

Here is the full code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  /* width: 100vw; not needed */
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.two {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.vertical {
  flex: 1;
}

.three {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: violet;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

.four {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: aqua;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

progress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 0;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="vertical">
      <progress max="100" value="80">
        <div class="progress-bar">
          <span style="width: 80%;">Progress: 80%</span>
        </div>
      </progress>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="three"> Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

Do you always forget how to vertically-align elements within a div, using CSS Grid? Don't feel alone, because I do too and I always end up here. Essentially, these two properties can be applied to the div containing elements that need to be vertically-centered:

```
.some-class {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkzhkeeh/1/) example for anyone curious on how these properties work.

**Resources**

- [grid-template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template)
- [justify items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items)
- [align items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

Comment: Such a much simpler solution

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer because of its simplicity and directly addresses the grid system (nothing to do with flexbox).

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: grid` and `align-items: center` to the `.two` div, but you could also use the `align-self: center` on the `.vertical` div if the usage of the `align-items: center` on the parent is avoided:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.two {
  display: grid; /* Added */
  align-items: center; /* Added */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4   ;
}

.three {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: violet;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

.four {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: aqua;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

progress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 0;
  height: 2em;
}

/* Optional, without the usage of the align-items: center; on the .two div
.vertical {
  align-self: center;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="vertical">
      <progress max="100" value="80">
        <div class="progress-bar">
          <span style="width: 80%;">Progress: 80%</span>
        </div>
      </progress>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="three"> Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the progress extra style. `position absolute`, `top`, and `transform: translate`.

Don’t forget to add `position:relative` to the parent of progress:

```
progress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: I have tried in codepen and it is working. How come not useful?

Comment: I guess because absolute positionning is not required and is not related to the GRID CSS system :( It is also in my personnal opinion a bad advise.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out a simple solutions. I believe it is CSS and will be related to any kind of GRID CSS system. But if you think it was bad and not required, no problem then. But its working anyway.