# How to vertically center elements inside a grid cell?

Tags: css, centering, css-grid

```
<div class='card'>
<div class='imgwrap'>...</div>
<div class='cardr'>
<a class='infor' href='...'>lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.card{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 54px auto;
}

.cardr{
    text-align:center;
    background:silver;
    align-items: center;  // line a
}

.infor{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #555;
    padding:4px 14px;
    border-radius:11px;
    background:gold;
    align-self:center;  // line b
}
```

I need `infor` to be both centered inside `cardr`.

Horizontally centering works using `text-align: center` and `display:inline-block`

Using `line a` and/or `line b` I want to center it vertically but without success.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536537/centering-in-css-grid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to add `.cardr { display: flex; }` and `.infor { margin: auto; }`.

This way `.infor` will be aligned both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @bonaca Glad it was helpful. You may want to change the title because infor is grandchild to the grid container. It would be helpful to other users.