# Span within div with grid cell alignment

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a `<span>` within a `<div>` within a grid, for example:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}
.label {
  align-self: center;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label">
    <span>Temperature</span>
  </div>
  <button>Add</button>
</div>
```

The first cell has to have a border that reaches the top border of the grid and the contents have to be centered in the grid cell. I cannot remove the span as it's coming from a component that does localization.

I'm aware that the vertical alignment could be done with flexbox but that seems like overkill...

Comment: possible duplicate: [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45536537/3597276)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't want to use flexbox, and it make sense  you can set `display:grid` in `.label`  and `align-self` in `span`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}
.label {
  display: grid;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.label span {
  align-self: center;
  margin: auto /* optional */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label">
    <span>Temperature</span>
  </div>
  <button>Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is probably the easiest way to do this.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}
.label {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label">
    <span>Temperature</span>
  </div>
  <button>Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvote? OP said 'flexbox seems like overkill' - doesn't mean it is.

Comment: Agreed. Flexbox is not "overkill" here and a good way to solve the problem.