# Grid item won't take full height of parent container

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, css-grid

I am trying to create three items inside of a nested grid item. As you can see from the code, I've put the 'panels' div in-between the 'jumbo' and 'content' divs. I also nested three divs inside. In the CSS, I added a nested grid inside of `.panels`.

I want the 'panels' div to be split in three equally size parts on the vertical axis. Imagine three square blocks stack one after another. But the nested items don't fill the entire 'panels' div. If you run the code snippet, you can see that the panels are nested but don't take up the entire space. They take up a small percentage of their parent. I added `background-color: white !important` to one of the nested panels to show how small it is.

Another example can be seen here: https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/NqQPBR/

But again, the nested E, F and G items don't expand to fill up the entire D section.

Is there a way to make the three panels fill in their parent?

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 40px 130px 130px 130px 60px 330px 40px;
}

.header {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.jumbo {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 2 / 5;
}

.panels {
    grid-column: 3 / 9;
    grid-row: 4 / 6;
    z-index: 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.panel1 {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: white !important;
    z-index: 2;
}

.content {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 5 / 7;
}

.footer {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

/* Styling */
.container > div {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffeead;
}

html, body {
    background-color: #ffeead;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "Work Sans"
}

.container > div:nth-child(1n) {
    background-color: #96ceb4;
}

.container > div:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color: #88d8b0;
}

.container > div:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #ff6f69;
}

.container > div:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color: #ffcc5c;
}

.panels > div:nth-child(1n) {
    background-color: #96ceb4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="jumbo">
        JUMBO
    </div>
    <div class="panels">
        <div class="panel1">PANEL1</div>
        <div class="panel2">PANEL2</div>
        <div class="panel3">PANEL3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You have `align-items: center` applied to the nested grid container (`.panels`).

With that rule, you override the default `align-items: stretch`, which would set your grid items to the full height of the parent. Instead, you have the items vertically centered.

So they can be full height, remove `align-items: center` from the `.panels` element:

```
.container > div:not(.panels) {
   align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 40px 130px 130px 130px 60px 330px 40px;
}

.header {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.jumbo {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 2 / 5;
}

.panels {
    grid-column: 3 / 9;
    grid-row: 4 / 6;
    z-index: 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.panel1 {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: white !important;
    z-index: 2;
}

.content {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 5 / 7;
}

.footer {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

/* Styling */
.container > div {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center; */
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffeead;
}

/* new */
.container > div:not(.panels) {
  align-items: center;
}

html, body {
    background-color: #ffeead;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "Work Sans"
}

.container > div:nth-child(1n) { background-color: #96ceb4; }
.container > div:nth-child(3n) { background-color: #88d8b0; }
.container > div:nth-child(2n) { background-color: #ff6f69; }
.container > div:nth-child(4n) { background-color: #ffcc5c; }
.panels > div:nth-child(1n)    { background-color: #96ceb4; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="jumbo">JUMBO</div>
    <div class="panels">
        <div class="panel1">PANEL1</div>
        <div class="panel2">PANEL2</div>
        <div class="panel3">PANEL3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Then, to vertically center the content of `.panels`, I would target the content directly:

```
.panels > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 40px 130px 130px 130px 60px 330px 40px;
}

.header {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.jumbo {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 2 / 5;
}

.panels {
    grid-column: 3 / 9;
    grid-row: 4 / 6;
    z-index: 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.panel1 {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: white !important;
    z-index: 2;
}

.content {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 5 / 7;
}

.footer {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

/* Styling */
.container > div {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center; */
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffeead;
}

/* new */
.container > div:not(.panels) {
  align-items: center;
}

/* new */
.panels > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

html, body {
    background-color: #ffeead;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "Work Sans"
}

.container > div:nth-child(1n) { background-color: #96ceb4; }
.container > div:nth-child(3n) { background-color: #88d8b0; }
.container > div:nth-child(2n) { background-color: #ff6f69; }
.container > div:nth-child(4n) { background-color: #ffcc5c; }
.panels > div:nth-child(1n)    { background-color: #96ceb4; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="jumbo">JUMBO</div>
    <div class="panels">
        <div class="panel1">PANEL1</div>
        <div class="panel2">PANEL2</div>
        <div class="panel3">PANEL3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that there are three structural levels in a grid container:

- the container
- the item (child of the container)
- the content (child of the item)

Grid properties only work between parent and child.

So when you apply grid centering properties on the container, they apply to the item, not the content. To center the content, you need to treat the item as parent and content as child.

There's a more in-depth explanation of these concepts and methods here: [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45536537/3597276)

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you have done is, you created three columns inside the 'panels' div:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

But you gave the children only a position for the row (twice):

```
grid-row: 1 / 2;
grid-row: 1;
```

So if you change 'columns' to 'rows' in '.panels' and clean up the code for '.panel1' it should work like a cham!

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have declared the rows twice. My mistake. I put that in later on accident. But even if I change those two lines, it doesn't fix the problem. How should I go about changing `grid-template-columns` in the panel div?

Comment: I'm sorry I think I haven't communicated properly what was wrong in your code. You have declared three columns, so the code does what it's supposed to do. Creating three different columns. A column is a "table cell" so it works on a row. What happens is that it will be placed next to each other. In order to get them underneath each other, you have to place them on different rows instead of columns. So change "grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);" to "grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);" and it does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions. I solved the issue by removing the nested 'panel' and simply creating three different panels to fill the same space.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 50px 218px 218px 200px 80px 530px 40px;
}

.header {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}

.jumbo {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 2 / 5;
}

.panel1 {
    background-color: white !important;
    z-index: 1;
    grid-column: 3 / 6;
    grid-row: 4 / 6;
}

.panel2 {
    background-color: black !important;
    z-index: 1;
    grid-column: 6 / 9;
    grid-row: 4 / 6;
}

.panel3 {
    background-color: purple !important;
    z-index: 2;
    grid-column: 9 / 12;
    grid-row: 4 / 6;
}

.content-left {
    grid-column: 1 / 5;
    grid-row: 5 / 7;
}

.content-right {
    grid-column: 5 / -1;
    grid-row: 5 / 7;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    align-items: start;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr)
}

.content-right > div {
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.footer {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.container > div {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffeead;
}

html, body {
    background-color: #ffeead;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "Work Sans"
}

.container > div:nth-child(1n) {
    background-color: #96ceb4;
}

.container > div:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color: #88d8b0;
}

.container > div:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #ff6f69;
}

.container > div:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color: #ffcc5c;
}

.panels > div:nth-child(1n) {
    background-color: #96ceb4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="jumbo">
        JUMBO
    </div>
    <div class="panel1">PANEL1</div>
    <div class="panel2">PANEL2</div>
    <div class="panel3">PANEL3</div>
    <div class="content-left">
        CONTENT-LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="content-right">
        <div class="content-right1">1</div>
        <div class="content-right2">2</div>
        <div class="content-right3">3</div>
        <div class="content-right4">4</div>
        <div class="content-right5">5</div>
        <div class="content-right6">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```