# Center grid div without items get centered

Tags: html, css, center, css-grid

Here are my code snippets:

```css
.grades_dashboard_m {}

.three_separation {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 60px;
}

.grades_dashboard_box {
  height: 130px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="grades_dashboard_m" id="co_1">
  <div class="three_separation">
    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
      <h1>12</h1>
    </div>

    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
      <h1>12</h1>
    </div>

    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
      <h1>12</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see the grid div (`grades_dashboard_m`) is not centered in `grades_dashboard_m`. How to center it without center the elements in `grades_dashboard_m`? I already tried this:

```
.grades_dashboard_m {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

But without success.

**EDIT**: *I figured out that this is not the problem. The problem is that the content of the 3 grids is not centered. But how to center the content of the grids?*

Comment: Please have a look at my solution as it directly answers your question using a grid-based property.

Comment: [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536537/centering-in-css-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply apply `margin: 0 auto;` to `.grades_dashboard_box`
likr this

```
.grades_dashboard_box {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

this shall center the element not text.

Answer (score 1):

### Pure, CSS Grid Solution

In short, *don't* use `margin: 0 auto` to center grid children—use `justify-items: center`.

```css
.three_separation {
  …
  justify-items: center;
}
```

A few words about `justify-items` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items):

> In grid layouts, it aligns the items inside their grid areas on the
>   inline axis

### Demo

```css
.grades_dashboard_m {}

.three_separation {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 60px;
  justify-items: center;  /* <-- Added */
}

.grades_dashboard_box {
  height: 130px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="grades_dashboard_m" id="co_1">
  <div class="three_separation">
    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
      <h1>12</h1>
    </div>

    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
      <h1>12</h1>
    </div>

    <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
      <h1>12</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @FilipDegenhart this is the *grid* way, using *margins* also works :)