# Centering CSS Grid Element

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I am using grid framework in css for that using following code

```
.grid {
        display: grid;
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        grid-gap: 8px;
        @media (min-width: 1440px) {
            grid-gap: 12px;
        }

        @media (min-width: 1920px) {
            grid-gap: 16px;
        }
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0
    }
.grid-col {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        width: auto
    }
    .grid-row-1 {
        grid-row: span 1
    }
    .grid-row-2 {
        grid-row: span 2
    }
    .grid-row-3 {
        grid-row: span 3
    }
    .grid-col-1 {
        grid-column: span 1
    }
    .grid-col-2 {
        grid-column: span 2
    }
    .grid-col-3 {
        grid-column: span 3
    }
    .grid-col-4 {
        grid-column: span 4
    }
    .grid-col-5 {
        grid-column: span 5
    }
    .grid-col-6 {
        grid-column: span 6
    }
    .grid-col-7 {
        grid-column: span 7
    }
    .grid-col-8 {
        grid-column: span 8
    }
    .grid-col-9 {
        grid-column: span 9
    }
    .grid-col-10 {
        grid-column: span 10
    }
    .grid-col-11 {
        grid-column: span 11
    }
    .grid-col-12 {
        grid-column: span 12
    }
```

Here is demo link
https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/yrd5p79v/

My problem is I am not able to center align columns using grid structure. I don't want to use flex I have to achieve this using grid. I want result like this. [Result using diplay inline-block](https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/c8aopb3y/2/) Please help me in this.

Comment: I cant put comment, so I should annswer.
refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536537/centering-in-css-grid

Comment: Hi @FatemehQasemkhani I have added what I want to achieve please check.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536537/centering-in-css-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with following code, hope it will work for you. here the align of content is set center as vertically and horizontally, and min-height is just for the checking the things work correctly.

Demo Link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/gmrj0nfk/1/

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  @media (min-width: 1440px) {
    grid-gap: 12px;
  }
  @media (min-width: 1920px) {
    grid-gap: 16px;
  }
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0
}

.grid-col {
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center; 
  min-height: 150px;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-row-1 {
  grid-row: span 1
}

.grid-row-2 {
  grid-row: span 2
}

.grid-row-3 {
  grid-row: span 3
}

.grid-col-1 {
  grid-column: span 1
}

.grid-col-2 {
  grid-column: span 2
}

.grid-col-3 {
  grid-column: span 3
}

.grid-col-4 {
  grid-column: span 4
}

.grid-col-5 {
  grid-column: span 5
}

.grid-col-6 {
  grid-column: span 6
}

.grid-col-7 {
  grid-column: span 7
}

.grid-col-8 {
  grid-column: span 8
}

.grid-col-9 {
  grid-column: span 9
}

.grid-col-10 {
  grid-column: span 10
}

.grid-col-11 {
  grid-column: span 11
}

.grid-col-12 {
  grid-column: span 12
}

@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
  .grid-col-xs-1 {
    grid-column: span 1
  }
  .grid-col-xs-2 {
    grid-column: span 2
  }
  .grid-col-xs-3 {
    grid-column: span 3
  }
  .grid-col-xs-4 {
    grid-column: span 4
  }
  .grid-col-xs-5 {
    grid-column: span 5
  }
  .grid-col-xs-6 {
    grid-column: span 6
  }
  .grid-col-xs-7 {
    grid-column: span 7
  }
  .grid-col-xs-8 {
    grid-column: span 8
  }
  .grid-col-xs-9 {
    grid-column: span 9
  }
  .grid-col-xs-10 {
    grid-column: span 10
  }
  .grid-col-xs-11 {
    grid-column: span 11
  }
  .grid-col-xs-12 {
    grid-column: span 12
  }
  .grid-row-xs-1 {
    grid-row: span 1
  }
  .grid-row-xs-2 {
    grid-row: span 2
  }
  .grid-row-xs-3 {
    grid-row: span 3
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .grid-col-sm-1 {
    grid-column: span 1
  }
  .grid-col-sm-2 {
    grid-column: span 2
  }
  .grid-col-sm-3 {
    grid-column: span 3
  }
  .grid-col-sm-4 {
    grid-column: span 4
  }
  .grid-col-sm-5 {
    grid-column: span 5
  }
  .grid-col-sm-6 {
    grid-column: span 6
  }
  .grid-col-sm-7 {
    grid-column: span 7
  }
  .grid-col-sm-8 {
    grid-column: span 8
  }
  .grid-col-sm-9 {
    grid-column: span 9
  }
  .grid-col-sm-10 {
    grid-column: span 10
  }
  .grid-col-sm-11 {
    grid-column: span 11
  }
  .grid-col-sm-12 {
    grid-column: span 12
  }
  .grid-row-sm-1 {
    grid-row: span 1
  }
  .grid-row-sm-2 {
    grid-row: span 2
  }
  .grid-row-sm-3 {
    grid-row: span 3
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) {
  .grid-col-md-1 {
    grid-column: span 1
  }
  .grid-col-md-2 {
    grid-column: span 2
  }
  .grid-col-md-3 {
    grid-column: span 3
  }
  .grid-col-md-4 {
    grid-column: span 4
  }
  .grid-col-md-5 {
    grid-column: span 5
  }
  .grid-col-md-6 {
    grid-column: span 6
  }
  .grid-col-md-7 {
    grid-column: span 7
  }
  .grid-col-md-8 {
    grid-column: span 8
  }
  .grid-col-md-9 {
    grid-column: span 9
  }
  .grid-col-md-10 {
    grid-column: span 10
  }
  .grid-col-md-11 {
    grid-column: span 11
  }
  .grid-col-md-12 {
    grid-column: span 12
  }
  .grid-row-md-1 {
    grid-row: span 1
  }
  .grid-row-md-2 {
    grid-row: span 2
  }
  .grid-row-md-3 {
    grid-row: span 3
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1280px) {
  .grid-col-lg-1 {
    grid-column: span 1
  }
  .grid-col-lg-2 {
    grid-column: span 2
  }
  .grid-col-lg-3 {
    grid-column: span 3
  }
  .grid-col-lg-4 {
    grid-column: span 4
  }
  .grid-col-lg-5 {
    grid-column: span 5
  }
  .grid-col-lg-6 {
    grid-column: span 6
  }
  .grid-col-lg-7 {
    grid-column: span 7
  }
  .grid-col-lg-8 {
    grid-column: span 8
  }
  .grid-col-lg-9 {
    grid-column: span 9
  }
  .grid-col-lg-10 {
    grid-column: span 10
  }
  .grid-col-lg-11 {
    grid-column: span 11
  }
  .grid-col-lg-12 {
    grid-column: span 12
  }
  .grid-row-lg-1 {
    grid-row: span 1
  }
  .grid-row-lg-2 {
    grid-row: span 2
  }
  .grid-row-lg-3 {
    grid-row: span 3
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1440px) {
  .grid-col-xl-1 {
    grid-column: span 1
  }
  .grid-col-xl-2 {
    grid-column: span 2
  }
  .grid-col-xl-3 {
    grid-column: span 3
  }
  .grid-col-xl-4 {
    grid-column: span 4
  }
  .grid-col-xl-5 {
    grid-column: span 5
  }
  .grid-col-xl-6 {
    grid-column: span 6
  }
  .grid-col-xl-7 {
    grid-column: span 7
  }
  .grid-col-xl-8 {
    grid-column: span 8
  }
  .grid-col-xl-9 {
    grid-column: span 9
  }
  .grid-col-xl-10 {
    grid-column: span 10
  }
  .grid-col-xl-11 {
    grid-column: span 11
  }
  .grid-col-xl-12 {
    grid-column: span 12
  }
  .grid-row-xl-1 {
    grid-row: span 1
  }
  .grid-row-xl-2 {
    grid-row: span 2
  }
  .grid-row-xl-3 {
    grid-row: span 3
  }
}

.grid-col-end {
  grid-column-end: -1
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  <div class="grid-col grid-col-12 grid-col-sm-4 grid-col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="c-book-tile">
      <div class="c-book-tile__body">
        Lorem ipsum
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-col grid-col-12 grid-col-sm-4 grid-col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="c-book-tile">
      <div class="c-book-tile__body">
        Lorem ipsum
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-col grid-col-12 grid-col-sm-4 grid-col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="c-book-tile">
      <div class="c-book-tile__body">
        Lorem ipsum
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you @Yudix_Wedesign but columns are not centering in container.

Comment: @vedankitakumbhar, can you please check now with "https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/f81oymxs/13/" demo.

Comment: Thank @Yudit_Webdesign but columns are not aligning at center

Comment: @vedankitakumbhar, have you check with latest jsfiddle link we share just above, because it works same as how you want without display inline-block. ('https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/f81oymxs/13/')

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .main {
      border: 2px solid #f76707;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #fff4e6;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .main>.box {
      border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #ffd8a8;
      padding: 1em;
      color: #d9480f;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .c-book-tile {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="box"><a href="#" class="c-book-tile">Lorem ipsum</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="#" class="c-book-tile">Lorem ipsum</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="#" class="c-book-tile">Lorem ipsum</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="#" class="c-book-tile">Lorem ipsum</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="#" class="c-book-tile">Lorem ipsum</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="#" class="c-book-tile">Lorem ipsum</a></div>
      <div class="box"><a href="#" class="c-book-tile">Lorem ipsum</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Piyush Thanks for reply but I want to centralize column not text inside columns

Comment: Hi @vedankitakumbhar  check me change  -  display:inline-block;

Comment: I don't want to use inline-block.

Comment: Okay  -  @vedankitakumbhar