# Flexbox: All columns in same height with centered text

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

**SOLUTION**: Sorry for duplicate, so, if you want make same height column with shorter content, this column must be flex too.

Final Solution:

```css
main article {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

PS: Sorry for duplicate

Original Post:

please, I have a problem to get same height of all column in my design. You can see it here:

https://codepen.io/littleTheRabbit/pen/ZEbBeGy

My problem is, that I want center (vertical and horizontal) `article` element content, but when I have to use `align-self: center` like here:

```css
main article {
    align-self: center;
}
```

my column doesn't same height like menu or like aside (of course, if I use `align-self: center` to `aside` the same problem.

I'm trying *google* answer but everything what I found was same height when you're using more rows in flexbox (and nothing centered :/)

> PS: As you can see I have full responsive menu. In left when you have big monitor, in all items when you have medium display and menu button in header when you have mobile without javascript :) Hopefully this can help someone

I'm trying add tricks like `flex-flow: 1 0 auto` into all children in `main` tag.

```css
main > * {
  flex-flow: 1 0 auto;
}
```

but nothing helps

Please any advice?

**PS: If is will be useful for future to other folks I can copy whole code here but I want keep it in my codepen all the time and I think that it doesn't need.**

Thank you very much for any adice

Comment: That's because you're using `align-self: center` to center the *flex item*, not the *content of the flex item*. Treat the flex item as a flex container. https://codepen.io/Figueroa5566/pen/pojNeZd?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, it works :) That means, any column which I want in the same height it must me ```display: flex``` too?

Comment: Yes. See the illustrations here for a clear understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599428/3597276

Comment: Thank you very much. Very useful link! Best regards