# How can I center this Iframes?

Tags: html, css

This is the html

```
<div class="main_content">
    <section class="episodio">
      <article class="contenedor_episodios">
        <h2>Episodios</h2>
        <div class="episodio_spotify">
          <iframe
            src="https://open.spotify.com/embed-podcast/show/2ySVrxGkN6n6frMTo9Nsrt"
            width="100%"
            height="225"
            frameborder="0"
            allowtransparency="true"
            allow="encrypted-media"
          ></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="episodio_spotify">
          <iframe
            src="https://open.spotify.com/embed-podcast/show/4kYCRYJ3yK5DQbP5tbfZby"
            width="100%"
            height="225"
            frameborder="0"
            allowtransparency="true"
            allow="encrypted-media"
          ></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="episodio_spotify">
          <iframe
            src="https://open.spotify.com/embed-podcast/show/5JxcIaIkN8zx3Zy7yD9snv"
            width="100%"
            height="225"
            frameborder="0"
            allowtransparency="true"
            allow="encrypted-media"
          ></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="episodio_spotify">
          <iframe
            src="https://open.spotify.com/embed-podcast/show/2Iibd5A6R7mxkCm4NwNmUn"
            width="100%"
            height="225"
            frameborder="0"
            allowtransparency="true"
            allow="encrypted-media"
          ></iframe>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
```

And this is the CSS for this piece of code.

```
    .main_content {
.episodio {
  grid-area: auto;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(#0000ff, #0000a3);
  .rectangle_background {
    .contenedor_episodio {
      display: grid;
      // justify-items: center;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
      .episodio_spotify {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex; /* new */
        align-items: center; /* new */
        justify-content: center;
        //grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 2fr));
        iframe {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Im tried different solutions to center this Iframes based on this question

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536537/centering-in-css-grid/45599428#:~:text=Use%20margin%3A%20auto%20to%20vertically%20and%20horizontally%20center%20grid%20items.&text=To%20center%20the%20content%20of%20grid%20items%20you%20need%20to,margins%20to%20the%20new%20elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536537/centering-in-css-grid/45599428#:%7E:text=Use%20margin%3A%20auto%20to%20vertically%20and%20horizontally%20center%20grid%20items.&text=To%20center%20the%20content%20of%20grid%20items%20you%20need%20to,margins%20to%20the%20new%20elements).

but I can't center the title Eposidios or the spotify Iframes.

Could someone please give an advice of what I'm missing?.

Regards

EDIT:

Im using a css query and for the mobile view is working fine i think the problem is that it keep taking the css code of the mobile view of 360 px

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1440px)  {

Comment: nit: better to format the code so it can be easier for others to read. something like https://beautifier.io/ or formatter in your ide

Comment: @fin I will do it and update the post thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```css
.episodio_spotify {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.episodio_spotify iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

hope I understood you well

Comment: Hi I found the solution my problem was that I had a div named .rectangle_background and since I deleted on previous versions the css I was using was not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

the solution to my problem was that I had a div named .rectangle_background and since I deleted on previous versions the css I was using was not working at all. – Andresfjobs just now   Edit