# centering a div in a grid item

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, centering

I've been trying to horizontally center a div on the screen of an Iphone.  The div is a bit narrower than the phone screen.  I have been googling and searching this site and trying every combination of display, flex, margin, width, justify*, align*, placeself, etc. etc. in the container as well as item style and nothing has worked.  Here is the code, with all my attempts removed from the style since none of it worked and I assume may interfere with correct solution.  No matter what I try, the div just stays on the left side of the screen.

{left} and {right} are divs, with width: 400px

```
    <Mobile>
        <Grid container style={{  }} >
            <Grid item xs={12} style={{  }}>{left}{right}</Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Mobile>
    

const Mobile = ({ children }) => useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 799 }) && children
```

Comment: possible guidance here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45536537/3597276

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBenjamin . That was one of the many many articles I read and tried.  I just tried again, what seemed like the part that was relevant, to make sure I didn't miss something.  Tried putting justifyItems: 'center', alignItems: 'center' in the grid item.  Did not work.

Comment: Ah.  Finally figured it out.  Thanks to you @MichaelBenjamin , I went through that page again, trying every possible combination.  Part of the problem was that I was using display: 'inlineGrid' instead of display: 'inline-grid' .  Still don't understand the logic of when to change things to camel case, so it's just trial and error til hopefully do one day :)  Ill post the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what finally worked for me after lots of trial and error.

```
    <Mobile>
        <Grid container style={{ justifyItems: 'center', alignItems: 'center', display: 'inline-grid', width: '100%' }} >
            <Grid item xs={12} style={{ width: '400px' }}>{left}{right}</Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Mobile>
```

To clarify, my question was probably inaccurate.  What I needed to do was center the grid item in the grid container.