# Centering elements in a grid layout in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm struggling to get a grid layout centered in Tailwind. Here's an example

```
    <div class="grid grid-cols-6 p-24 justify-center bg-slate-500">
        <div class="w-full p-8 col-span-2 justify-center justify-self-center mx-auto bg-slate-900 text-white text-center text-lg">
            2 cols, should be centered
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's what that looks like:

[image]

Of course I could add col-start-2 and then it would be centered, but the grid is coming from a dynamic layout and I don't know whether there are more elements coming on the same row or not. I've tried justify-center, justify-self-center, mx-auto, also played around with no-float but nothing works.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Read this for a thorough understanding of grid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599428/9920079

Comment: Thank you @Hackinet, very useful. I don't think it actually covered what I was looking for, which specifically was centering one of the grid items. It was more about centering the content within the grid, rather than having a grid with for example 3 columns and centering when there are just 2 elements within it. But still very interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
      <div class="grid grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fit,_16.666666%)] m-auto p-24 justify-center bg-slate-500">
        <div class="w-full p-8 col-span-2 justify-center justify-self-center mx-auto bg-slate-900 text-white text-center text-lg">
          2 cols, should be centered
        </div>
      </div>
```

You may want to [specify the `repeat(auto-fit, 16.666666%)` as part of your theme.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#customizing-your-theme)

You also may want to consider what exactly you want to happen when there are more than three items - if you need a fifth and last element to also be centered, then maybe a flexbox would serve you better.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-6 p-24 bg-slate-500">
  <!-- Empty columns for spacing -->
  <div class="col-span-2"></div>
  
  <!-- Centered 2-column section -->
  <div class="col-span-2 flex justify-center">
    <div class="w-full p-8 bg-slate-900 text-white text-center text-lg">
      2 cols, centered
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Empty columns for spacing -->
  <div class="col-span-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).