# Images scaling incorrectly in grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to display a simple grid with square images. I was surprised to find out that it doesn't work properly when images are direct children of the grid. Images get too large, overlapping each other.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
}

img {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: orange;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1920x1080">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1920x1080">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1920x1080">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1920x1080">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1920x1080">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1920x1080">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1920x1080">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1920x1080">
</div>
```

It works correctly if I apply `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` to `img`, but I'm trying to understand why.

Is there some additional way of handling image sizes inside the grid? Why do they require explicit dimensions when the grid should already instruct them of such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do they require explicit dimensions when the grid should already instruct them of such?

Where does the grid provide these instructions? It doesn't.

Your rule `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr))` sets up the columns. It doesn't apply to the content inside those columns.

Without adding `width: 100%` to the images, they compute to their intrinsic size, which in this case is 1920 x 1080.

As a general practice in HTML/CSS, add `img { width: 100%; height: auto }` to prevent images from overflowing their containers.

Comment: But images ARE the columns, right?

Comment: No. The images are content inside the columns. The columns are tracks created by the grid container.

Comment: You could argue that the images are the columns in flexbox. But grid operates a bit differently, having actual rows and columns, not just flex lines.

Comment: This is interesting, I have never thought about that this way.

Comment: This answer may provide more clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599428

Comment: Gonna give it a read, thanks Michael!