# Removing underline from flex child

Tags: html, css, flexbox, underline

The traditional way to remove text-decoration from only a child element was to make it an `inline-block`. *(Example 1 in Fiddle)*

However, this method does not work in flexbox.

How can I remove the underline from just the icon in *Example 2*?

```
.div1 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    .icon {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

}
.div2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    .icon {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mz4y3jgL/8/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the content in a `span` element, like you've done for the icon.

Anonymous flex items, such as unwrapped text, cannot be targeted with CSS ([related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43027851/3597276)).

```css
.div2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.div2 > :not(.icon) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="div2">
  <span>Example 2</span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great solution.